# Menu management options in Drupal 7

Tags: routes, nodes

On node add/edit form, when the navigation menu grows, it becomes harder to find the menu parent in which we want to add the node link. Is there any module through which it becomes little easier?

Secondly, on the menu management page where it displays all the menu items, is it possible to drag multiple menu items? Is there any menu management module like the Taxonomy manager module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) - with "hs_menu" submodule this module allow built "hierarchical" select of parent for menu.